# Matplotlib Bar Plot with two Y-Axis and Common X-Axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to plot matplotlib bar plot with one y-axis on the left and another y on the right with a common x-axis.The range column is on the x-axis. Perc column is on left y-axis and the count column is on the right y-axis. Please advise how to proceed.

Sample data is here - [SampleFileHere](https://ufile.io/4wbcw)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = td['perc'].plot(kind="bar", alpha=0.7)
plt.xticks(td['ranges'].tolist())
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),td['count'],marker='o', c='navy', linewidth=4)
```

I get the below error .

```
<ipython-input-24-c1d398c0d012> in <module>()
      7 fig = plt.figure()
      8 ax = td['perc'].plot(kind="bar", alpha=0.7)
----> 9 plt.xticks(td['ranges'].tolist())
     10 ax2 = ax.twinx()
     11 ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),td['count'],marker='o', c='navy', linewidth=4)
```

Comment: I am trying to provide a link to the excel. Please hold on . I am just searching how to do

Comment: Have provided the link to data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the xticks to some non-numeric values. Instead you need to set the xticklabels to the entries from the "range" column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counts = np.array([56000,900,5000,6000,30000,3500,300]).astype(float)
perc =  counts/counts.sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({"range": list("ABCDEFG"),"count":counts, "perc":perc})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = df['perc'].plot(kind="bar", alpha=0.7)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df['count'],marker='o', c='navy', linewidth=4)

ax.set_xticklabels(df['range'])
ax.set_ylim(0,1.3*df["perc"].max())
ax2.set_ylim(0,1.3*df["count"].max())
ax2.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]